# Issues rounding up values regardless of its precision in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and I am trying to write an SQL query to roundup values in a different way from the usual way. My query is able to round up to 2 decimal places

```
SELECT
    "ID",
     round("Cash", 2) AS "Balance",
    "Currency"
FROM
    "lex"
where "ID" = 101
```

in cases where cash = `100.065` it is rounded to `100.07` which is good.
I also want to round up cash = `100.061` to `100.07`

Is this doable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CEIL function should do that but it will round up any value so be careful with your precision

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ceil.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simple method is simply adding a value of 0.005 when rounding:

```
    round(cash + 0.005, 2)
```

**EDIT**: But you may need a case statement that looks at the 3rd digit after the decimal, and if a 0, then don't add 0.005. Just depends on your data and use case for rounding up.